# Inversion of Hopf's Umlaufsatz

Tags: differential-geometry

[Hopf's Umlaufsatz](http://warwickmaths.org/files/Curvature.pdf#page=4) (better known as?) says:

> Let $\gamma$ be a simple closed differentiable positively oriented
>   curve in the plane. Then for its curvature $\kappa$ it holds:
>
> $$\int_{\gamma}\kappa\ \text{d}s = 2\pi$$

I wonder if (and cannot see why not) the inversion holds, too:

> Let $\kappa$ be a continuous function $\kappa: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\kappa(0) = \kappa(1)$ and $\int_0^{1}\kappa\ \text{d}s = 2\pi$. Then there is a simple closed differentiable
>   positively oriented curve $\gamma$ (of length 1) with curvature $\kappa$.

(If this holds, $\gamma$ would be unique upto congruency via Euclidean motions.)

Comment: Sometimes this is called the 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem, as in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). // Yes, one can reconstruct a curve from its curvature, as on second page [here](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ag4-gm/handouts/06gm_curves.pdf).

Comment: @5PM:  A planar curve can be reconstructed from it's curvature, but the question is if the curve is closed or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is another necessary condition on $\kappa$.  The so-called Four vertex theorem:

> **Theorem**:  Suppose $\kappa$ is the curvature of a simple closed curve.  Then, either $\kappa$ is constant or has at least 2 minimums and 2 maximums.

The ellipse shows that there is no reason to expect *more* than 2 minimums or maximums of curvature.

It turns out that together with your integral condition and this condition together are necessary and sufficient for $\kappa$ to correspond to a closed simple curve.  A write up, due to DeTurck, Gluck, Pomerleano, and Vela-Vick, (who say the result is due to Dahlberg) can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0609/0609268.pdf).  See also a more informal (but similar) write up by Vela-Vick [here](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~shea/notes/fourvertextalk.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, now I remember reading about the theorem long time ago... Now I also see that @Hans wanted length $1$, which is not guaranteed by the construction as far as I can tell... Or maybe Hans even wanted an arclength parametrization? I hope he'll clarify.

Comment: @5PM:  I missed the unit length part.  In that case, I'm not sure what more needs to be added.