# Applying to Gauss-Bonnet in the Angle-Sum Theorem and Circumference Theorem.

Tags: geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am studying about the Gauss–Bonnet Theorem in context of Riemannian Manifolds. I'm following the book "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds" of John Lee. In the text, is defined the signed curvature of $\gamma$ (a curved polygon) as
$$k_N (t) = g(D_t \gamma'(t), N(t)),$$
where $D_t \gamma'(t)$ is the covariant derivative of $\gamma'(t)$ over $\gamma$ and $N$ is a unique unit normal vector field along the smooth portions
of $\gamma$ such that $(\gamma'(t), N(t))$ is an oriented orthonormal basis for $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for each $t$ .

**Theorem (The Gauss–Bonnet Formula)**: Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Riemannian 2-manifold. Suppose $\gamma$ is a positively oriented curved polygon in $M$, and $\Omega$ is its interior. Then
$$\int_{\Omega} K dA + \int_{\gamma}k_{N} ds + \sum_{i=1}^k \varepsilon_i = 2\pi,$$
where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of $g$, $dA$ is its Riemannian volume form,
$\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_r$ are the exterior angles of $\gamma$, and the second integral is taken with respect to arc length.

The author claims that from the Gauss–Bonnet formula follow as easy corollaries:

**Corollary 1 (Angle-Sum Theorem)**. The sum of the interior angles of a Euclidean
triangle is $\pi$.

**Corollary 2 (Circumference Theorem)**. The circumference of a Euclidean circle
of radius $R$ is $2\pi R$.

As objects are flat, then $K = 0$ in two cases. My difficulty lies in proving these corollaries, especially regarding the calculation of $k_N$.

For the Corollary 1, denoted by $\theta_i$ the interior angle, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \theta_i = \sum_{i=1}^3(\pi - \varepsilon_i) = 3 \pi - \sum_{i=1}^3 \varepsilon_i = 3 \pi - (2\pi + \int_{\gamma}k_{N} ds) = \pi + \int_{\gamma}k_{N} ds.$$
I'm having trouble showing that this integral is indeed $0$.

For the Corollary 2 we have: the circumference not have angles then:
$$2\pi = \int_{\gamma}k_{N} ds,$$
how to get the result from that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to [Hopf's Umlaufsatz](https://mathematik.com/Hopf/). It states that the rotation of the unit normal about a closed curved is zero for the Euclidean plane.

Comment: On site [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275930/inversion-of-hopfs-umlaufsatz)

Answer (score 1):

For Corollary 1, the sides of the triangle are geodesics so $k_N = 0$ since $D_t\gamma'=0$.

For Corollary 2, do the computation explicitly by setting $\gamma(t) = (R\cos\theta,R\sin\theta)$. A calculation shows that $k_N = 1/R$, so
$$
\int_\gamma k_N ds = C/R,
$$

where $C$ is the length of $\gamma$.